# Unable to send html file content as email body in python

Tags: python, html, smtp

I have a html file whose contents I want to send in the email body using python. Below is the python script:

```
import smtplib,email,email.encoders,email.mime.text,email.mime.base
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
import codecs

msg = MIMEMultipart()
# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "a@b.com"
you = "b@a.com"


# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = "Automation Testing"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
f = codecs.open('/Users/test.htm')
html =  f.read()

part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')


# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.

msg.attach(part2)

composed = msg.as_string()

fp = open('msgtest.txt', 'w')
fp.write(composed)

# Credentials (if needed)  
# The actual mail send  
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.a.com', 25)  
server.starttls()
server.sendmail(me, you, composed)  
server.quit()  
fp.close()
```

But, it is sending only an empty email with no html content in the body. Please tell me how to fix this.